# C# - Is it possible to create new local Guid variable, automatically whenver a method is being called?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I am looking to implement Guid trace mechanism for every method that is being called but I don't want to write this on every method:

Guid TraceId = Guid.NewGuid()

Is there an attribute or some other way that can automatically generate Guid whenever a method is being called and have it stored/available as local variable?

For MVC ApiControllers I used this logic, but I need it to happen for different class types as well.

```
[TraceActionFilter]
public class TracedApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    public TracedApiController()
    {

    }
    public string TraceId
    {
        get
        {
            return ActionContext.ActionArguments[TraceActionFilterAttribute.TRACE_ID].ToString();
        }
    }

    public Guid TraceIdGuid
    {
        get
        {
            return Guid.Parse(TraceId);
        }
    }
}

public class TraceActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(TRACE_ID))
        {
            actionContext.ActionArguments.Add(TRACE_ID, Guid.NewGuid());
        }
        else actionContext.ActionArguments[TRACE_ID] = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public static string TRACE_ID = "TraceId";

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. So every time the _same_ method is called you need a new different Guid from any previous one generated for the same method?

Comment: Is your goal to reinvent the wheel for educational purposes (writing logging frameworks is traditional developers' past time) or you don't know better?

Comment: If existing logging frameworks do not meet your requirements - have a look at using [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#overview-of-dependency-injection) for managing per-request lifetimes of dependencies.  In this case, your trace id provider could be added as a scoped dependency.